# Solving complex equation ${{\left( z+2\bar{z} \right)}^{3}}=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Hey i am stuck tring to solve :
$${{\left( z+2\bar{z} \right)}^{3}}=1$$

I used Binomial theorem to expand the equation to :
$${{z}^{3}}+6{{z}^{2}}\bar{z}+12z{{\bar{z}}^{2}}+8{{\bar{z}}^{3}}=1$$
and i am not sure how should i continue

Comment: Write $z$ as $a+b\mathrm{i}$, and $\bar{z}=a-b\mathrm{i}$ where $a$ and $b$ are real.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here $$(z+2\bar{z})^3 = 1\Rightarrow (z+2\bar{z}) = (1)^{\frac{1}{3}} = 1,\omega,\omega^2.$$

Where $\omega,\omega^2$ are cube root of unity.

So $$z+2\bar{z} = 1,\omega,\omega^2.$$

Now Put $z=x+iy$ and $\bar{z} = x-iy$

$\bullet\; $ If $z+2\bar{z} = 1\;,$ Then $x+iy+2(x-iy) = 1\Rightarrow 3x-iy=1+0\cdot i$

So we get $\displaystyle x = \frac{1}{3}$ and $y=0$

$\bullet\; $ If $z+2\bar{z} = \omega\;,$ Then $\displaystyle x+iy+2(x-iy) = -\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\Rightarrow 3x-iy=-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

So we get $\displaystyle x = -\frac{1}{6}$ and $\displaystyle y=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

$\bullet\; $ If $z+2\bar{z} = \omega\;,$ Then $\displaystyle x+iy+2(x-iy) = -\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\Rightarrow 3x-iy=-\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

So we get $\displaystyle x = -\frac{1}{6}$ and $\displaystyle y=+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

So we get $$\displaystyle z = \left\{\frac{1}{3}+0\cdot i\;\;,-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cdot i\;\;,-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cdot i\right\}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** write $1=e^{2\pi i}$ and begin by taking the cube root. Now solve for real and imaginary parts separately.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Try substitution $z=x+yi$, $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint...$$z+2\bar{z}=e^{i(\frac{2\pi}{3}+n.2\pi)}$$ and $z=x+iy$